# Does LiquiBase generate invalid SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-update, liquibase

For my MySql database I have a LiquiBase changeset that looks like this:

```
<changeSet id="ddl update tables : modify datatype for MY_TABLE.STATE_ABBREV" author="xxx">
    <preConditions onFail="MARK_RAN" onFailMessage="Column MY_TABLE.STATE_ABBREV doesn't exists.">
        <and>
            <tableExists tableName="MY_TABLE"/>
            <columnExists tableName="MY_TABLE" columnName="STATE_ABBREV"/>
        </and>
    </preConditions>
    <update tableName="MY_TABLE">
        <column name="STATE_ABBREV" value="AS"/>
        <where>AGU
        </where>
    </update>
</changeSet>
```

This will result in

```
UPDATE MY_TABLE SET STATE_ABBREV = 'AS' WHERE AGU;
```

This does not look like valid ANSI SQL. Is this a LiquiBase bug or does LiquiBase do anything with this SQL before submitting to the database? 
How can I tell LiquiBase to generate well-formed ANSI SQL?

Comment: Well you provided an invalid condition in your changeset: `<where>AGU</where>` so the generated SQL is invalid as well. `where agu` is actually valid ANSI SQL **if** (and only if) `agu` is a boolean column (which SQL Server does not have). MySQL does not have a (real) boolean data type as well. But it simply treats any value that is not zero as "true". `where '1xyz'` would also do the same thing in MySQL.

Comment: Please have a look at: http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/changes/update.html
This shall edit a varchar column.